# How to run android emulator with sd card

Tags: java, android

I download and build android 1.5r3 source.
I did 'launch 1' and then 'make'.

And when it is done, I run my emulator like
out/host/darwin-x86/bin/emulator  -sdcard sd256m.img

But when I click 'Gallery', it said 'No Media Found'.
I am sure the sd card i created (sd256m.img) has images in there.

Can you please tell me why I don't see any images in the sd card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you make that SDCard image file? Did you create it with the AVD tool or did you use mksdcard? Also, did you try it by specifying the full path to the sd256m.img file?

Links for posterity: [Using SDCards with the emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#sdcard)

Comment: i use the mksdcard tool.

I have tried using full path as well. But that does not work either.

Comment: If you use adb to connect to the running emulator, are you able to see anything in the /sdcard directory?

Comment: Ok, so if I understand this correctly then, you created the SD card image and at one point were able to mount it and put files on there? At some point the images were lost? Have you attempted to put more files on the SD card since then and see if they are accessible between emulator restarts?

Comment: Hi MattC I am also having the same problem. I put some image file in a folder and create .iso file using PowerISO. then I create sdcard using 'mksdcard'>then emulator -sdcard sdcard1.iso -avd Any. but no images in the gallery!

Comment: you have to be kidding me.. to access files on the sd card, I have to create an iso..  Wow.. this emulator just gets easier and easier to use.